# How do I notify eclipse that my custom launch has terminated?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I a writing an eclipse plugin and I created a custom launch configuration.

I created a class implementing `org.eclipse.debug.core.model.LaunchConfigurationDelegate` and named `com.some.package.MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate`. `LaunchConfigurationDelegate`'s only method is `launch(...)`.

I then added my class as an attribute of the `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes` extension point :

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes">
    <launchConfigurationType
        name="My Launch Configuration Name"
        delegate="com.some.package.MyLaunchConfigurationDelegate"
        modes="run"               
        id="com.som.package.MyLaunchConfigurationId">        
    </launchConfigurationType>
</extension>
```

Everything works fine, my `launch` method is executed and terminates normally.

Now **the problem is my launches are not marked as terminated**. As a consequence, I cannot remove them.

This has no effect :

```java
launch.terminate();
```

Right now I'm doing this to work around the problem, but this is not very eclipse-like :

```java
DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().removeLaunch(launch);
```

Comment: Are they *supposed* to disappear without user intervention? By default, terminated launches remain.

Comment: Yes you're right. But my launches are not marked as terminated either, so I can't remove them. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The terminated status usually comes from the `IProcess.isTerminated()` method.